# Is there a way to turn my python script (that I wrote in an Ubuntu docker image) into an executable for Windows?

Tags: python

Made a python script in Ubuntu, but I read that pyinstaller compiles based on the operating system, so if I compile it on Ubuntu, it'll be for Ubuntu. How can I make an executable in Ubuntu, for Windows, or do I have to export my script into my Windows OS and compile it there?

Comment: You will need to compile on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

From [PyInstaller’s documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#supporting-multiple-operating-systems):

> If you need to distribute your application for more than one OS, for example both Windows and Mac OS X, you must install PyInstaller on each platform and bundle your app separately on each.

So, yes, you generally must run PyInstaller on the operating system the emitted binary will be run on. The documentation does suggest using a virtual machine and that running PyInstaller with WINE may work.